# How to Lazy-Load a React Native module from a path stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactjs-flux, loadable-component

I've been trying to load a **React Native** component dynamically, but to no success. It seems like **React Native** doesn't like it at all when you try passing it a module **path** stored in a variable :

This works very well - [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) :

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./path/to/my/module'));
```

This also works like a charm Full dynamic import : - [Full dynamic import : @loadable/component](https://loadable-components.com/docs/loadable-vs-react-lazy/#full-dynamic-import)

*(npm @loadable/component)*

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
const AsyncPage = loadable(props => import('./path/to/my/module'))
```

but try changing any to this :

```
var myModulePath = './path/to/my/module';  

const AsyncPage = loadable(props => import(myModulePath))
```

or this :

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import(myModulePath));
```

and all goes crazy!

How can I go about loading a module dynamically, say at *runtime*, or just have the path briefly held in a variable, instead of passing it as a `string literal`

From the documentation ([Full dynamic import : @loadable/component](https://loadable-components.com/docs/loadable-vs-react-lazy/#full-dynamic-import)),

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component'
const AsyncPage = loadable(props => import(`./${props.page}`))
```

a dynamically generated path should work, but my *React Native* attempts don't.

Are there any ideas out there?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push

About lazy loading, it is not needed if you use the Hermes JS engine. Otherwise, you can use RAM bundler: https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires